# How can I set a buffer-local variable (format-all-mode) to nil within .dir-locals.el? (using Doom emacs)

Tags: doom, directory-local-variables, buffer-local, local-variables

I have a project where I want to disable `format-all-mode` for all my python files. I can do this manually by running `M-x format-all-mode` every time I open up a python file for that project.

I tried automating this by setting my `.dir-locals.el` to this:

```
((python-mode
  (eval . (progn
          (make-local-variable 'format-all-mode)
          (setq format-all-mode nil)))
))
```

I've also tried:

```
((python-mode
  (eval . (progn
         (format-all-mode nil)))
))
```

but `format-all-mode` continues to be `t` every time I open a python file. I've confirmed that my `.dir-locals.el` settings are otherwise working, because when I add something like `(setq blah "asdf")` inside the `progn` function, I see that variable in my buffer.

What am I missing in order to configure the buffer-local `format-all-mode` variable?

Here are the docs when I describe this `format-all-mode` variable:

```
format-all-mode is a buffer-local variable defined in format-all.el.

Value in #<buffer my-file.py>
t

Buffer values Global value Toggle Set

Documentation
Non-nil if Format-All mode is enabled.

Use the command format-all-mode to change this variable.

Key Bindings
This command is not in any keymaps.

References
References in format-all.el:
(define-minor-mode format-all-mode ...) 2 references

Find all references
```

---

### Update

I should've mentioned that I'm using Doom emacs, which has modified the format-all-mode so that it cannot be disabled with the usual `(format-all-mode -1)`.

I followed these instructions: https://docs.doomemacs.org/latest/modules/editor/format/

and got it working with the following value in my `.dir-locals.el`:

```
((python-mode
  (eval . (progn
        ;; this doesn't work, because we're using doom emacs:
        ;; (format-all-mode -1)
        ;;
        ;; https://docs.doomemacs.org/latest/modules/editor/format/
        ;; TODO: add python-mode to the list, instead of overwriting the whole list
        (setq +format-on-save-enabled-modes
          '(not python-mode sql-mode org-mode emacs-lisp-mode))
  ))
))
```

It's a hack though, since `+format-on-save-enabled-modes` isn't buffer local. I'm not sure if there's a better way - any help is appreciated!

Comment: To disable a minor mode, you call it with a negative argument, so try `((python-mode (eval . (format-all-mode -1))))`. I didn't check the syntax though.

Comment: Hmm I tried that, but it's still not working... Note that the docs mention `Non-nil if Format-All mode is enabled.` (I referenced the output above)

Comment: You need to call the *function* `format-all-mode` with a negative argument. If the mode is disabled, then the *variable* `format-all-mode` should automatically be set to `nil`. Setting the variable does *not* disable the mode in general. So try this: open a python file, check the variable (which should be `t` if the mode is automatically enabled); then do `M-: (format-all-mode -1)` to disable the mode and check the variable again: it should now be `nil`. If that's all as it should be, then you have to make sure that the syntax of your entry in the `.dir-locals.el` file is correct.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the tips! You are correct. This helped me narrow down the issue, which I detailed at the bottom of my updated post. Looks like there's some complications due to me using Doom emacs, and while I have a workaround as described, it's pretty hacky.

Comment: Just to update this thread, philz answer below provides an elegant solution to make this work with Doom emacs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is about disabling a minor mode, but just to answer the stated question of setting a buffer-local variable, it's as simple as this:

```el
((python-mode . ((format-all-mode . nil))))
```

I.e. giving variables buffer-local values is what the most basic syntax of `.dir-locals.el` is for.  There is no need to complicate anything with `eval`.

Note that if you ever use `(eval . (setq VAR VALUE))` in a `.dir-locals.el` file and `VAR` is *not* already/automatically buffer-local, then you are setting the **global** value.  I would suggest using `setq-local` as standard in that situation.

In your case, and per the quoted docs, you need to:

> Use the command format-all-mode to change this variable.

Where the *command* is the function itself, which is interactively callable via `M-x`.

(Because changing the variable is not the real goal; the variable is merely intended to be a *reflection* of whether or not certain other functionality is active, and the function controls that functionality.)

So you *would* use `eval` if you needed this to be a buffer-local thing, but you'd do that to call the function:

```el
((python-mode . ((eval . (format-all-mode 0)))))
```

n.b. I'm also assuming that `format-all-mode` is a buffer-local minor mode.  If it's a global mode, then the above would disable its behaviour globally as soon as you visited a python file under that directory.  (Global modes need to be handled on a case-by-case basis, as how they operate can be highly variable.)

---

Edit: From the comments, this particular case needed something different again, but a working solution turns out to be:

```el
((python-mode . ((+format-on-save-enabled-modes . nil))))
```

I.e. in `python-mode` buffers, for files under the dir-locals directory, we give `+format-on-save-enabled-modes` the buffer-local value of `nil`.  Testing has confirmed that this has the desired effect of preventing the format-on-save behaviour for those files.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions disables the format-all minor mode for me, I think because Doom emacs has its own hooks which prevents that. I posted an update to my question above which explores some workarounds, but it still feels very hacky. I appreciate this answer though - it's helped me understand these fundamentals a bit more. Happy to mark this as an accepted answer if it helps others.

Comment: I don't use doom or this mode, but looking at your update, you might try `((python-mode . ((+format-on-save-enabled-modes . (not python-mode)))))` -- whether that works would very much depend on the manner in which `+format-on-save-enabled-modes` is used, but it seems worth a try.

Comment: Or maybe `((python-mode . ((+format-on-save-enabled-modes . nil))))` is a slightly cleaner option.  I don't know anything about this variable though, so that's purely a guess.

Comment: Amazing! Your suggestion above works perfectly: `((python-mode . ((+format-on-save-enabled-modes . nil))))` I'm still wrapping my head around buffer-local variables, but it seems like setting +format-on-save-enabled-modes in this manner is specific to `python-mode` and correctly uses the default for all other modes. This is exactly what I needed. I should probably read up on how this actually works, but for now, I'm thrilled to have this working as expected :D

Comment: I'm glad that worked.  My guess is that the format-on-save functionality is triggered in `before-save-hook` for the specific buffer being saved, checks the value of `+format-on-save-enabled-modes` at that point in time, sees the buffer-local value, and therefore does nothing.

Comment: You've correctly understood the .dir-locals.el behaviour -- the buffer-local value is being set *only* for file buffers which are in `python-mode`; other buffers are unaffected.